# Which of the existing normality tests are true when you have a lot of data? a million data for example

Tags: r, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, inference, normality-assumption

From the following list of normality test: Shapiro wilks, Anderson Darling, Cramer-Von mises, Kolmogorov-smirnov, pearson and shapiro fancia. Which of these tests is useful for a lot of data? for example more than a thousand data

Comment: In R, the Shapiro-Wilk test ([`shapiro.test`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/shapiro.test)) limits samples to 5000 observations. I haven't checked them all, but other tests may have size limits for theoretical or technical computational reasons.

Comment: But ability to 'make the test work' without an error message does not guarantee useful results. // If $n$ is too small, no test is reliable. If $n$ is huge, the null hypothesis of normality may be rejected because of small and inconsequential imperfections in the data. // E.g., from 100,000 iterations of the S-W test with $n=5000,$ in R with `shapiro.test(rt(5000, 50))$p.val` over 1/4 showed P-values below 5% in spite of the fact that it Student's t dist'n with DF=50 is very nearly normal. For some purposes, this may illustrate the power of the test. For others, it may be 26,516 false alarms.

Comment: Probably none of them ... what is useful is plots, like qq-plots.